# How can i implement facebook like newsfeed in my application in android?

Tags: image, android-listview, android-viewpager, feed

I want to develop newsfeed for my application. I have taken viewpager as listview row item and loading images from server into viewpager. But main problem is that all viewpager loading same images. How can i solve this issue?